# How to get next value in column where the date changes in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has multiple rows for a single date:

```
Date      | Value| Desired Output
2023-01-01| 1000  | 1002
2023-01-01| 1000  | 1002
2023-02-01| 1002  | 1004
2023-03-01| 1004  | 1006
2023-04-01| 1006  | 1009
2023-04-01| 1006  | 1009
2023-05-01| 1009  |
```

I would like to create a column that has the value of the next date in the row.

Answer (score 1):

Drop duplicate on `Date`, set it as index, shift and map:

```
df['expected'] = df['Date'].map(df.drop_duplicates('Date')
                                  .set_index('Date')['Value'].shift(-1)
                               )
```

Output:

```
         Date  Value  expected
0  2023-01-01   1000    1002.0
1  2023-01-01   1000    1002.0
2  2023-02-01   1002    1004.0
3  2023-03-01   1004    1006.0
4  2023-04-01   1006    1009.0
5  2023-04-01   1006    1009.0
6  2023-05-01   1009       NaN
```